# The requested resource () is not available

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to complete a simple servlet. I have installed Tomcat 6.0 and jdk 1.7.0. I have followed my book (Apress.Beginning.JSP.JSF.and.Tomcat.Web.Development) instructions to create this servlet. The address to my servlet is http://localhost:8080/ebookshop/ But when I type this address in my browser I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The requested resource () is not available.

web.xml file content is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=~CCC
    "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <display-name>Electronic Bookshop</display-name>
    <description>
    e-bookshop example for
    Beginning JSP, JSF and Tomcat: from Novice to Professional
    </description>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>EBookshopServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ebookshop.ShoppingServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EBookshopServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/eshop</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Does any body know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The servlet is mapped to `/eshop` in the web.xml file, inside the context path of your application. So, if your webapp's war file or directory is indeed named `ebookshop`, the URL to your servlet is

```
http://localhost:8080/ebookshop/eshop
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. I found the problem. There was some extra characters in my web.xml file. you can see that. "xsi:schemaLocation=~CCC". "~CCC" was making the problem.